# Segfault when <ctrl> + <leftflick> an unfocused window of a CygwinX QT app

Tags: c++, qt, cygwin, xserver

When ctrl + leftclick the **unfocused** window of a QT application launched via Cygwin X, I am noticing a very repeatable segfault. At this point I've trimmed off all of my application code and can still see the same behavior while running a simple QMainWindow holding a few empty TextEdits. A simple left click into the unfocused window (while holding ctrl) will cause a segfault ~50% of the time.

Has anybody noticed a similar behavior? I'm very curious since I don't seem to see this behavior documented or reported elsewhere.

**Note:** I've noticed that this behavior applies to all Modifier keys (alt, ctrl, shift, etc).

```
#0  0x00007f8429cf614b in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#1  0x00007f8429cee501 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#2  0x00007f8429ce9e20 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#3  0x00007f8429ceb0cb in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#4  0x00007f84306c955e in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f84311f25b4 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#6  0x00007f84311f5991 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#7  0x00007f84306a27c4 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f84306a4701 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007f84306ea0d3 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007f842e7e3f05 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#11 0x00007f842e7e4248 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007f842e7e4304 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#13 0x00007f84306ea514 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00007f84306a169b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007f84306a4c3e in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/local/lib/qt5/5.0.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
```

Comment: This is probably best reported [directly to cygwin](http://cygwin.com/problems.html).

Comment: Can you run it under debugger and see where the error happens? What Qt version are you using?

Comment: I've updated the question with a sample corefile, hopefully that can help. I'm running Qt 5.0.2

Comment: Can you compile it for Windows (no Cygwin), and verify the problem doesn't happen there? Also can you check if the bug happens in the newest stable version of Qt?